# How do I modify every nth element of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am working with the Mathematica S&P 500 data

`datasp=Prepend[ExampleData[{"Statistics", "SP500"}],ExampleData[{"Statistics", "SP500"}, "ColumnHeadings"]];`

and have to multiply every 20th element by 203.63. In a next step, I will have to calculate the sum of all elements from the list (including the elements that have not been multiplied).

Unfortunately, I am struggling a bit with this. Could anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep track of your data by creating a new list, `datasp1 = datasp;`. Manipulate every 20th element of the new list, `Table[datasp1[[i]] = 203.63 datasp1[[i]], {i, 20, Length@datasp, 20}]` (notice that the step is set to 20 so every 20th element is changed; if you need to ignore the header, start at 21). Verify, `datasp1[[40]]/datasp[[40]]`. Sum them with `Total@datasp1`.

Comment: Thanks you're a hero!

Comment: Another possibility is `datasp1[[ ;; ;; 20]] *= 203.63`.

Comment: Carl, would you please explain how your code works? I neither understand how `Span Span 20` produces a loop with a step of 20 nor how `*=` works in this setting.

Comment: @NicholasG The syntax of Carl is short for `datasp1[[ 1 ;; Length[datasp1] ;; 20 ]]`. It says: take element `1` to `Length[datasp1]` in steps of `20`. This line takes every 20th element of datasp1 and multiplies it by 203.63. For more info look up the documentation of `Part`